# Laravel : Saving a belongsToMany relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to save a new signature in my table signature.
Each signature can be linked to multiples users. 
I have a many to many table between Users and Signatures.

My Model Signature is :

```
class Signature extends Model {
   public $fillable = ['name', 'template'];

   public function users() {
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
   }
}
```

My Controller SigantureController.php is :

```
public function store(CreateSignaturesRequest $request)
{
    //return $user_id;
    $values = $request->only(['name','template']);

    Signature::create($values));

    return response()->json(['message'=>'SUCCESS'], 201);

}
```

How can I do to Create my Signature and link it to a user ?

I tried

```
Signature::create($values)->associate($user_id);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Considering your tables are users, signatures and user_signatures

Define the relation in model: User.php

```
class User extends Model {
   public function signatures() {
       return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Signature', 'user_signatures');
   }
}
```

Define the inverse of the relation in model: Signature.php

```
class Signature extends Model {    
   public function users() {
       return $this->belongsToMany('\App\User', 'user_signatures');
   }
}
```

In your controller you could do the following:

```
//create a new signature
$signature = new Signature($values);
//save the new signature and attach it to the user
$user = User::find($id)->signatures()->save($signature);
```

The opposite is possible too:

```
$user = User::find($user_id);
$signature = Signature::create($values)->users()->save($user);
```

Alternatively if you have an existing signature you should do:

```
$user = User::find($id);
$user->signature()->attach($signature->id);
```

Please note that attach() and detach() accepts an id or an array of ids.

Laravel docs has covered this in much more details and better examples. You should check attach(), detach() and sync() methods. Please have a look: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#inserting-related-models

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It happens that I have a relational table named user_signature and not signature_user, so this command gives me an error because the targeted table doesn't exists. Do you know what I need to do ?

Comment: Change the second argument in your belongsTo method with the appropriate table name. That should pick it up nicely.

Comment: There is a typo on the last code line $user->signature() without "s" at the end of signature.

Answer (score 9):

You need to have a table called `user_signature` with the following schema:

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
$table->integer('signature_id')->unsigned();

$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
$table->foreign('signature_id')->references('signatures')->on('users');
```

Then your `User` model should have the following method:

`Model User`

```
public function signatures() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Signature');
}
```

Now that you have developed the `Many-To-Many` relationship between the models what you can do is this:

While storing a new record (the controller you are using for the signature):

```
 /**
 * Insert the signature
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @return ...
 */
 public function store( Request $request ) {
    // your validation

    $signature->users()->attach( $request->input('user_id') );

    // return
}
```

Similarly while updating the record (the controller you are using for signature):

```
/**
 * Update the signature with the particular id
 *
 * @param $id
 * @param Request $request
 * @return ...
 */
 public function update( $id, Request $request ) {
    // your validation

    $signature->users()->sync( $request->input('user_id') );

    // return
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, very clear answer ! However, I need to do the storing in the signature side; not in the user side. Is that possible ? How ?

Comment: I have edited the answer, you can have a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

First of all `associate` requires a model object to be passed as arguments. See here: http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsTo.html#method_associate

Is is also for `belongsTo` relationships, not `Many to Many` as is in your case. See here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#inserting-related-models

Based on that what you should do is:

```
Signature::create($values)->users()->attach($user_id);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It happens that I have a relational table named user_signature and not signature_user, so this command gives me an error because the targeted table doesn't exists. Do you know what I need to do ?